# Can not clone my repository in my own git server

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, hostname

I am trying to clone my repository from and in my own gitlab server but this is what i get

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.domain.com/user/repo.git/': Could not resolve host: git.domain.com
```

but cloning works outside my git server.

Any ideas why my server can't resolve the host but other machines can ?

Comment: Try to remove last `/`

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov this is how i clone it 'git clone http://git.domain.com/user/repo.git .' but then i get that error

Comment: is valid repo address ? i tried, it says `not found`

Comment: @ThiruShetty are u kidding me ? ofcourse it will not be found because its a example domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

`37.xx.xxx.xxx   git.domain.com`

to

`/etc/hosts` file resolved my issue.